# Send data to database when click on a link without page refresh

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql, ajax

Is there a way to send data to database when click on a link without page refresh?

I use php/mysql...

Comment: You have already listed the ways in your tags...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I will give you an example using jQuery.

Let's say that we have a link with an attribute id="button_id" (you have to learn the jQuery selectors ).

```
    $("#button_id").click(function(){
    var var_data = 5;
    $.ajax({
            url: "my_script.php",
            data: { var_PHP_data: var_data };
            success: function(data) {
                // do something;
                                  alert(data);
            },
     });
});
```

Explanation: you will send the variable `var_data` with the name `var_PHP_data` to a `my_script.php` without page refresh using an ajax call (using GET method).

This is very simple example of what you have to write on your PHP script.

```
<?php
$var_name = $_GET['var_PHP_data'];
echo 'This is what you have send'.$var_name;
```

?>

Because the default method to send variables in the `ajax function in jQuery is GET`.

We have to use the $_GET function in PHP.

This php script will print a message and this message will be handled in the `success: function` in the Ajax call and just for example we will alert this message returned from PHP.

Answer (score 1):

You'd have to use JavaScript.  When a user clicks a link, if you don't use JavaScript, then you need to go user -> server -> user and they get a whole new page.

HTTP is stateless.

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible without a page refresh but this is the classic use-case for [AJAX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29) requests. If you're not familiar with AJAX then there are various methods of doing this using all the popular JavaScript frameworks such as [Prototype](http://www.prototypejs.org/api/ajax/request) and [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/)

Answer (score 0):

You can't send data directly to a database, but you can use AJAX to send data to a php page that will save them to the database, without reloading the page or following the link in the browser..

Have a look at  http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

Answer (score 0):

Not using PHP because it is server side - you need JavaScript / AJAX for this.

Check out frameworks like dojo (http://www.dojotoolkit.org/) , mootools (http://mootools.net/) or jQuery ( http://jquery.com/ ).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use AJAX.

This is a very big topic, but I'd recommend you do some research on AJAX and jquery (javascript).

Here are some tutorials:

http://www.ajaxf1.com/tutorial/ajax-php.html

http://www.talkphp.com/vbarticles.php?do=article&articleid=58&title=simple-ajax-with-jquery

Do a search in google for more info.