# Javascript X/Y Coordinates into database?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql

Ive been asking this question over and over many times in a bad way, so ill try to make it clearer.

I have a page with HTML that has an Attack and Restart Link on the page, the restart link appears after you win.

These links are JavaScript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--

function attack() { 
window.location = "attack.php?attack=1";
}


function restart() {
window.location = "battle.php?id=1&status=start";
}

-->
</script>
```

I want to make it so that once the person has clicked one of these link, (using javascript) it gets the X/Y coords of where the clicked the link and inserts it into the database with the following values:

```
id
ip
username
x
y
restart
```

For the id, ip, username and restart I could easily use MYSQL and PHP, but I dont know how to insert Javascript information into the database, which would be the X/Y coords.

Comment: `PHPMyAdmin` is web application to manage your database. It is not something you send data to.

Answer (score 1):

Using the Insterstellar_coder's X/Y javascript snippet, you could use javascript to make an ajax call to a php script. The ajax call would contain all the parameters as arguments and the php script on the server could get these arguments and do the database insertion.

Edition (20111016211256-0400): added files to show a solution (as far as I understand correctly the issue):

I've worked only the attack part. the restart part is similar.

No AJAX part was needed since I did piggyback on your attack and restart php files.

---

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title>index</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

        // get continous mouse move events and keep the coordinates in tempX and tempY
        // stolen from http://javascript.internet.com/page-details/mouse-coordinates.html
        var IE = document.all?true:false;
        if (!IE) document.captureEvents(Event.MOUSEMOVE)
        document.onmousemove = getMouseXY;
        var tempX = 0;
        var tempY = 0;
        function getMouseXY(e) {
            if (IE) { // grab the x-y pos.s if browser is IE
                tempX = event.clientX + document.body.scrollLeft;
                tempY = event.clientY + document.body.scrollTop;
            }
            else {  // grab the x-y pos.s if browser is NS
                tempX = e.pageX;
                tempY = e.pageY;
            }  
            if (tempX < 0){tempX = 0;}
            if (tempY < 0){tempY = 0;}  
            return true;
        }



        var ip = "10.0.0.1";
        var username = "me";
        var id = "1";

        function Coordinates(x,y) {
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
        }

        function attack(e) { 
            window.location = "attack.php?attack=1&x="+tempX+"&y="+tempY+"&ip="+ip+"&username="+username+"&id="+id;
        }


        function restart() {
            window.location = "battle.php?id=1&status=start";
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body id="index" onload="">
    <input type="button" name="attack" value="attack" id="attack" onClick="attack();">
    <input type="button" name="restart" value="restart" id="restart" onClick="restart();">

</body>

</html>
```

---

attack.php

```
<?php

$METHOD = '_' . $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];
foreach ($$METHOD as $key => $value) {
    $$key = $value;
}

$log = array("attack" => $attack, "x" => $x, "y" => $y, "ip" => $ip, "username" => $username, "id" => $id);
//print_r($log);

try {
    // assuming you use mongodb locally
    $m = new Mongo(); 
    $db = $m->mydb;
    $logs = $db->logs;
    $logs->insert($log, true);
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo $e; 
} 

?>
```

Comment: How would I go about doing this? :/

Comment: Have a look at http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_database.asp this is for reading but writing use the same stategy.

Comment: I still have no idea in how to insert JS information into the Database. ;-;

Comment: I'll give you more detailed info when I get back home tomorrow. In the mean time, can you tell me which db you are using?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the pageX and pageY coordinates from the event object. Here is some rough code.

```
$('yourlinkid').click(function(e){      
     var x = e.pageX; // x coordinate
     var y = e.pageY; // y coordinate
});
```

Comment: So it would be:

$('attack').click(function(e){      
     var x = e.pageX; // x coordinate
     var y = e.pageY; // y coordinate
}); 

But then what? o_O
How do I go about inserting all the information? :/

Comment: @sirwuffles: Have a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3178247/send-data-to-database-when-click-on-a-link-without-page-refresh) and [these](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavascript%5D+send+data+to+mysql). This has been ask before, you just have to search for it. And I'm pretty sure that you'll also find a lot information using Google.

Comment: `window.location = "attack.php?attack=1&x="+x+"&y="+y;`

Comment: So is this how its supposed to be?

`function attackONE() { $('attackONE').click(function(e){ var x = e.pageX; // x coordinate var y = e.pageY; // y coordinate }); window.location = "battle.php?attack=1&x="+x+"&y="+y";"; }`

Answer (score 0):

There's an epic library for this called [`Touché`](https://github.com/davidcalhoun/touche). It gives you a lot of information about the user interaction with the page (e.g clicking, dragging). You can also specify callbacks for AJAX purposes if you want to send data to the database or maybe do something else.

Here's the [`demo`](http://davidbcalhoun.com/a/touche.html)